# how to install lafilefixer in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, freeswitch, lua

I am getting following error while installing freeswitch on Ubuntu.

libtool: link: cannot find the library `/usr/src/freeswitch/libs/apr-util/xml/expat/lib/libexpat.la' or unhandled argument`/usr/src/freeswitch/libs/apr-util/xml/expat/lib/libexpat.la'

I read from a forum that this problem can be solved if I install lafilefixer and run "lafilefixer --justfixit". But I don't find a any way to install lafilefixer. Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expat is an XML parser library written in C. [project website](http://expat.sourceforge.net/)

You need to download the package from [project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/)

Read installation instructions from the README file. Basically you need to

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Have a look at the "Makefile" to learn about additional
"make" options.  Note that you need to have write permission into
the directories into which things will be installed.